# Facebook API import album only working for me not for other users?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a site where a user that logs in with their Facebook account will access their Albums and pictures on the my website. What code do i have to put in my website to do this.
i am able to getting all the general information fro all the users who is logged in, but not their ambles and pictures.
All the code work fine only when ,i logged in with my Facebook id then it give my all the information pictures and albums also. i want this thing work for all the users.
I have read a lot of documentation from Facebook and on stack overflow but i cant find an answer, 
Here is my [demo Link](http://collage.bluecoresys.com/demo/examples/exm.php)

Here is my Code :

```
    require '../php-sdk/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$user_id = $user; 
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();


$SESSION['token']="CAAHk9LIIji4BAMLZCNFVMDSNEZCZCc5zfb80c8Nq4wrLZBqY56o3ZARrO3FZC9qPWXHdYpH5jZBaaADWsZBKZAdViKA5eQlKcFK579SOlOq2CXms8ZAqGZAJdXsUZAH2ZCtqPZASn3A8ZB7VXFxb4WFjPJTPUNDQlZBZCtqHcJNZA3TRozriLDCjjRdsPp5Bad9Mu1J9CdGJQZD";
 $SESSION['token']=  $access_token;
echo $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=" . $SESSION['token'];
$photos = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/'.$user_id);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}


?>

 <?php if ($user): ?>

  <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
<?php else: ?>
  <div>
    Check the login status using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
    <a href="<?php echo $statusUrl; ?>">Check the login status</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
    <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>

<h3>PHP Session</h3>
<pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

<?php if ($user): ?>  

  <h3>You</h3>
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">
  <pre><?php print_r($user_albums); ?></pre>
  <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
  <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
<?php else: ?>
  <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
<?php endif ?>

<h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
<?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>


if ($user) {
       echo "album";
    // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
    // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
    try {

        $params = array(
            'method' => 'get',
            'access_token' => $access_token
        );

        if (isset($_GET['aid']) && $_GET['aid'] != '') {
            $aid = $_GET['aid'];
            $user_album_photos = $facebook->api('/' . $aid . '/photos', $params);
            //echo "Photos<br/>"; 
            ?>

            <?php foreach ($user_album_photos['data'] as $key => $value) {
                ?>
        <div class="album">
         <div class="frame photo_frame">
        <div class="edit-photo-nohover" style="display:block">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="fbimport_id<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" value="<?= $value['id'] . ',' . $value['images']['0']['source'] . ',' . $value['name'] ?>" name="fbimport[]" > <span>Import this Memory</span></div>

                        </div>
                        <table class="test">
                            <tr><td>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="<?= $value['images']['0']['source'] ?>" height="100" width="100" /></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <h3 id='bottomcaption'><?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3>
                    </div><br/>
                </div>
                <?php }
            ?>


        <?php
        } else {
            $user_albums = $facebook->api('/'.$user_id.'/albums', $params);
            echo '<h3 class="page-title">Select Your Facebook Album</h3><br/><br/>';
            foreach ($user_albums['data'] as $key => $value) {

                /* load album if not blank */
                if (isset($value['count']) && $value['count'] != '' && $value['count'] != NULL && $value['count'] > 0) {

                    /* check if album has a cover photo. if not than load a default image */
                    if (isset($value['cover_photo']) && $value['cover_photo'] != '' && $value['cover_photo'] != NULL) {
                        $user_album_cover = $facebook->api('/' . $value['cover_photo'], $params);
                        $album_thumbnail = $user_album_cover['images']['0']['source'];
                    } else {
                        $album_thumbnail = 'default_thumb.gif';
                    }
                    /* check if album has cover photo end */
                    ?>
                    <div class="album">
                        <div class="frame photo_frame">
                            <table class="test">
                                <tr><td>
                                        <a href="?aid=<?= $value['id'] ?>" ><img src="<?= $album_thumbnail ?>" height="100" width="100" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <h3 id='bottomcaption'><?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3>
                        </div><br/>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                }//if(isset($value['count']) && $value['count'] != '' && $value['count'] != NULL && $value['count']>0)
                /* load album if not blank end */
            }
        }
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
} else {

    // No user, print a link for the user to login
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to ask the user for permission to use their pictures. You need to pass in a array of permissions into the function that gets the login url. The permission you need is  "user_photos".

See these links for more information:

[Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/)

[Documentation for getLoginUrl](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/)

Comment: @DavidJones i m asking bit late..but i'm having same issue .`$params = array("scope" => "user_photos");      // define scope of app
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);    // get login url for login` still i can fetch data from my account only not users

Comment: @DavidJones i have added scope in loginmethod but not working

Comment: @software I'm afraid I haven't used the Facebook API since I asked this question. I imagine this code is out of date.

Comment: @DavidJones yes right it got changed over the years. but i thought method to call api remains the same . i searched over the web . but could not get solution for new version. there are some errors while i m trying the code.

Comment: @software I guess you could checkout the documentation. If you're still having issues you could open a new question on here.